# TensorFlow: multithreaded unbatching of datasets

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am using TensorFlow 2.0 beta. I have a TensorFlow `Dataset` where each element is a batch of feature columns: a tuple of tensors where each has the values of a particular feature for `batch_size` records. I need to flatten these records for serialization as `TFRecords`, which I would like to do using TensorFlow `Dataset` functions. The flattened records do not need to be produced in a deterministic order.

Here is some example code demonstrating what I am trying to accomplish:

```
batch_size = 100
num_batches = 10
input_data = (tf.constant(['text_data']), tf.constant(13))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(input_data).repeat(batch_size * num_batches)
ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
# ds = ... (multithreaded data transformations on batches of records happen here)
ds = ds.unbatch()
```

The problem is that the methods that I have tried to do so either do not work or form a major bottleneck because they are single-threaded. Here are some of those approaches:

1. `unbatch` - single-threaded, too slow
2. `interleave`/`flat_map` - `flat_map` doesn't accept on tuples of tensors - "takes 2 positional arguments but" [num_features] "were given"
3. `interleave`/custom function with `py_function` - doesn't work because `py_function` can't return a `Dataset`
4. `interleave`/custom function without `py_function` - doesn't work because in graph mode, can't iterate over tensors

I need to replace `unbatch` with some way of distributing batches to multiple threads, which independently unbatch them, then interleave the results from the different threads. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the version that I ultimately found, using `interleave` with `from_tensor_slices`:

```
batch_size = 100
num_batches = 10
num_threads = 4
input_data = (tf.constant(['text_data']), tf.constant(13))
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(input_data).repeat(batch_size * num_batches)
ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
# ds = ... (multithreaded data transformations on batches of records happen here)
ds = ds.interleave(lambda *args:tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(args), num_threads, 1, num_threads)
```